# Change Elastic Beanstalk deployment content based on environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm building a WordPress site using [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/) and I am hoping to use AWS CodePipeline and Elastic Beanstalk for deployments.

I already have my pipeline and EB application set up and seemingly working correctly. However, I would like to change some behaviors depending on what environment variables are set:

In a nutshell, if the environment is set to "Development", I'd like to deploy my Bedrock project as normal:

```
Development:/
|-- web/
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- wp-cli.yml
`-- ...
```

I'd like to keep my composer.json and other dev dependencies so that a developer can access the development server via Cloud9 and develop remotely.

But if the environment is set to production, I would only like to deploy only the `web/` folder.

```
Production:
  web/
```

I've looked into setting an `.ebignore` file, but I am not sure how to go about altering this value based on the environment. I've also looked into setting up an `.ebextensions` folder that contains commands and container_commands, which seems promising, but I am unsure of the best practice to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using CP, you could add a CodeBuild stage before you deploy to EB. The CB stage would modify your deployment artifact based on your environment. This could include changes to folder structures, `.ebextensions` files, and anything else that you need. So your CP would look like:

```
Source stage ---> CodeBuild stage ---> Deployment to EB stage
```